# neo4j query: return obj1.*, obj2.name

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4j, how to return like: `return obj1.*, obj2.name`
now, I write like this will cause: `**Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `.*` syntax isn't going to work, because cypher isn't SQL.  :)

If you simply do `return obj1`, that node shows up like a map when output by `neo4j-shell`.  That seems to me like what you're trying to accomplish.   But there isn't a way to separate out oall of `obj1`'s properties individually and make them new columns in the result.